# frameworks missing in xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

m new to iphone development and download a number of sample codes for reference, but frameworks are always missing in those sample codes. I tried to add them by clicking on frameworks and choose "add Existing Framworks" but there also I cant found the basic frameworks(CoreGraphics, UIKit and Foundation) Frameworks.

How can I add those Frameworks to run my downloaded sample code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the project in your sidebar -> select your target -> Build Phases -> Link binary with libraries -> click the plus sign.  Do they show up there under iOS 4.x?

Comment: on clicking the Link binary libraries i cant found any Plus sign ???Wat to do now ????

Comment: When you click Link with libraries, the box expands to reveal the libs you are currently linking against. On the bottom left of the expanded box there should be a +/- .

Comment: Thanks for your help. I fix it !!! actually m working on xcode 4.2 and the sample code is taking default xcode i.e. 4.0. when I change the settings code is running successfully !!