# Unable to launch app using calabash ios 10 and xcode8

Tags: xcode, code-signing, ios10, xcode8, calabash-ios

Am trying to launch the application in iOS 10 devices  with calabash 0.20.0 version.. But am getting error..

I have updated complete setup and error details listed down:

Our Current Work Environment:

---

gem env

---

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/bsachi001c/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@tvx-mobile-automation
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/bsachi001c/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/bsachi001c/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/bsachi001c/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@tvx-mobile-automation/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/bsachi001c/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/bsachi001c/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/bsachi001c/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@tvx-mobile-automation
     - /Users/bsachi001c/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/bsachi001c/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@tvx-mobile-automation/bin
     - /Users/bsachi001c/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin
     - /Users/bsachi001c/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin
     - /Users/bsachi001c/.rvm/bin
     - /Users/bsachi001c/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
     - /Users/bsachi001c/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/tools
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin

Gem list:

---

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

ansi (1.5.0)
awesome_print (1.7.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.8)
briar (2.0.4)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.13.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
calabash-android (0.8.2)
calabash-cucumber (0.20.0)
CFPropertyList (2.3.3)
clipboard (1.1.1)
coderay (1.1.1)
command_runner_ng (0.1.0)
cucumber (2.4.0)
cucumber-core (1.5.0)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
deordinalize (0.0.3)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
domain_name (0.5.20160826)
dotenv (2.1.1)
edn (1.1.1)
escape (0.0.4)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
geocoder (1.4.0)
gherkin (4.0.0)
http-cookie (1.0.3)
httpclient (2.8.2.4)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.5)
json (1.8.3)
luffa (2.0.0)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1, 2.99.3)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.8.3)
multi_json (1.12.1)
multi_test (0.1.2)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
netrc (0.11.0)
nokogiri (1.6.8)
pkg-config (1.1.7)
power_assert (0.2.6)
pry (0.10.1)
psych (2.0.17)
rainbow (2.1.0)
rake (10.4.2)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
rdoc (4.2.1)
rest-client (2.0.0)
retriable (2.0.2)
rspec (3.5.0)
rspec-core (3.5.4)
rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
rspec-support (3.5.0)
ruby-ole (1.2.12)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubyzip (1.2.0)
run_loop (2.2.1)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
slop (3.6.0)
slowhandcuke (0.0.3)
spreadsheet (1.0.3)
test-unit (3.1.5)
thor (0.19.1)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.2)
xamarin-test-cloud (2.0.2)
yajl-ruby (1.2.1)

Ruby -v

---

ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]

Xcode,iOS and MAC versions:

---

Mac OSX :10.11.6 
iOS version:10.0.2
Xcode version:8.0

xcrun security find-identity -v -p code signing  ====> 4 valid identities found ( all are automation team’s account)

We have received a ipa file from the developers team, who has linked ipa file with calabash_framework 0.20.0
 export APP=/Users/bsc/Documents/workspace/mobile-automation/iOS/tablets/master_Debug.ipa
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: xxxxxx@gmail.com (W95FEZS38E)"    DEVICE_TARGET="9ef528263f678e344c12a2eb922653c217e34177"    DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://x.x.71.43:37265 bundle exec cucumber
Below error message we are getting it..

Could not install /Users/bsachi001c/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@tvx-mobile-automation/gems/run_loop-2.2.1/lib/run_loop/device_agent/ipa/DeviceAgent-Runner.app.  iOSDeviceManager says:

2016-10-05 10:26:37.412 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] MobileDevice: Loading from /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.415 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] MobileDevice: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.415 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Loaded All Private Frameworks [MobileDevice]
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.599 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DTXConnectionServices: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTXConnectionServices.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.600 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DTXConnectionServices: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.600 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DTXConnectionServices: DTXConnection has correct path of /Applications/Xcode.app
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.600 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DTXConnectionServices: DTXRemoteInvocationReceipt has correct path of /Applications/Xcode.app
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.600 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTFoundation: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.616 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTFoundation: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.617 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTFoundation: DVTDevice has correct path of /Applications/Xcode.app
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.617 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEFoundation: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.620 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEFoundation: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.620 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework DVTAnalytics.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.620 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTAnalytics.framework could not be loaded from fallback directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.620 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTAnalytics: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTAnalytics.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.621 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTAnalytics: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTAnalytics.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.621 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework DVTServices.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.621 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTServices.framework could not be loaded from fallback directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.621 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTServices: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTServices.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.623 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTServices: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.623 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTServices.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks', re-attempting to load DVTAnalytics
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.624 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTAnalytics: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTAnalytics.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.624 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework DVTAnalyticsClient.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.624 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTAnalyticsClient.framework could not be loaded from fallback directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.624 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTAnalyticsClient: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTAnalyticsClient.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.625 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTAnalyticsClient: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.625 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTAnalyticsClient.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks', re-attempting to load DVTAnalytics
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.626 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTAnalytics: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.626 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTAnalytics.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks', re-attempting to load IDEFoundation
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.627 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEFoundation: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.628 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework DVTPortal.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.628 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTPortal.framework could not be loaded from fallback directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.628 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTPortal: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTPortal.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.629 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTPortal: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.629 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTPortal.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks', re-attempting to load IDEFoundation
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.631 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEFoundation: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.631 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework DVTSourceControl.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.631 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTSourceControl.framework could not be loaded from fallback directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.631 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTSourceControl: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTSourceControl.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.647 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTSourceControl: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.647 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTSourceControl.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks', re-attempting to load IDEFoundation
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.649 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEFoundation: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.649 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework SourceKit.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.650 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] SourceKit.framework could not be loaded from fallback directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.650 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] SourceKit: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/SourceKit.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.653 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] SourceKit: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.653 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] SourceKit.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks', re-attempting to load IDEFoundation
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.665 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEFoundation: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.665 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEFoundation: IDEFoundationTestInitializer has correct path of /Applications/Xcode.app
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.665 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DevToolsFoundation: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsFoundation.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.667 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DevToolsFoundation: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.667 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DevToolsSupport: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsSupport.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.669 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DevToolsSupport: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.669 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DevToolsCore: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.674 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DevToolsCore: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.674 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEiOSSupportCore: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.683 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEiOSSupportCore: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.684 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEiOSSupportCore: DVTiPhoneSimulator has correct path of /Applications/Xcode.app
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.684 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IBAutolayoutFoundation: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.686 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IBAutolayoutFoundation: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.686 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework IBFoundation.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.686 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IBFoundation: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBFoundation.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.694 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IBFoundation: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.694 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IBFoundation.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks', re-attempting to load IBAutolayoutFoundation
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.696 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IBAutolayoutFoundation: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.696 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEKit: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.699 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEKit: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.699 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework DVTProducts.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.699 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTProducts.framework could not be loaded from fallback directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.699 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTProducts: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTProducts.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.701 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTProducts: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.701 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTProducts.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks', re-attempting to load IDEKit
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.702 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEKit: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.702 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework DADocSetManagement.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.702 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DADocSetManagement.framework could not be loaded from fallback directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.702 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DADocSetManagement: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DADocSetManagement.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.703 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DADocSetManagement: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DADocSetManagement.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.703 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework DVTKit.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.704 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTKit.framework could not be loaded from fallback directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.704 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTKit: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.715 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTKit: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.715 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTKit.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks', re-attempting to load DADocSetManagement
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.716 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DADocSetManagement: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DADocSetManagement.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.716 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework DADocSetAccess.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.716 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DADocSetAccess.framework could not be loaded from fallback directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.717 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DADocSetAccess: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DADocSetAccess.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.722 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DADocSetAccess: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.722 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DADocSetAccess.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks', re-attempting to load DADocSetManagement
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.723 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DADocSetManagement: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.723 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DADocSetManagement.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks', re-attempting to load IDEKit
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.725 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEKit: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.725 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework DVTDeveloperModeHelper.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.725 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTDeveloperModeHelper.framework could not be loaded from fallback directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.725 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTDeveloperModeHelper: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDeveloperModeHelper.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.726 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTDeveloperModeHelper: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.726 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DVTDeveloperModeHelper.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks', re-attempting to load IDEKit
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.727 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEKit: Bundle could not be loaded from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework, attempting to find the Framework name
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.727 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Attempting to load missing framework DTGraphKit.framework
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.727 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DTGraphKit.framework could not be loaded from fallback directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.727 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DTGraphKit: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTGraphKit.framework 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.729 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DTGraphKit: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.729 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] DTGraphKit.framework has been loaded from fallback directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks', re-attempting to load IDEKit
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.740 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDEKit: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.740 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDESourceEditor: Loading from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESourceEditor.ideplugin 
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.744 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] IDESourceEditor: Successfully loaded
  2016-10-05 10:26:37.745 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Loaded All Private Frameworks [DTXConnectionServices, DVTFoundation, IDEFoundation, IDEiOSSupportCore, IBAutolayoutFoundation, IDEKit, IDESourceEditor]
  2016-10-05 10:26:43.018 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] EXEC: /usr/bin/xcrun security find-identity -v -p codesigning
  2016-10-05 10:26:43.083 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237322] EXEC: /usr/bin/xcrun security cms -D -i /Users/bsachi001c/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/f26bd0d7-3ab7-42da-a2e6-a9b0b499dfe7.mobileprovision -o /var/folders/h2/q9ywrcbs6w327h78fljhbv280_x7vl/T/A4AD339C-98A1-456B-ADEE-E7462B2A3545-12863-000012B54576FF96.plist
  2016-10-05 10:26:43.083 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237312] EXEC: /usr/bin/xcrun security cms -D -i /Users/bsachi001c/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/b105019a-d9b1-4035-afb2-16dd50689191.mobileprovision -o /var/folders/h2/q9ywrcbs6w327h78fljhbv280_x7vl/T/4A8622E7-E2FB-4A1B-9BC5-B43A99FB15CF-12863-000012B545768D63.plist
  2016-10-05 10:26:43.083 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] EXEC: /usr/bin/xcrun security cms -D -i /Users/bsachi001c/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/1961aa1f-efdb-444e-98da-f39a48b65e27.mobileprovision -o /var/folders/h2/q9ywrcbs6w327h78fljhbv280_x7vl/T/89C9D99D-1E49-45A9-AC79-DC392E320D44-12863-000012B5457668ED.plist
  2016-10-05 10:26:43.153 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] EXEC: /usr/bin/xcrun security cms -D -i /var/folders/h2/q9ywrcbs6w327h78fljhbv280_x7vl/T/4ADB341C-5CC4-43C7-BF5B-F16A1E082537-12863-000012B5333F73A5/DeviceAgent-Runner.app/embedded.mobileprovision -o /var/folders/h2/q9ywrcbs6w327h78fljhbv280_x7vl/T/B9C55E92-65FC-4336-8732-A9220BB9440D-12863-000012B549A5D5E1.plist
  2016-10-05 10:26:43.190 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] EXEC: /usr/bin/xcrun codesign -d --entitlements :- /var/folders/h2/q9ywrcbs6w327h78fljhbv280_x7vl/T/4ADB341C-5CC4-43C7-BF5B-F16A1E082537-12863-000012B5333F73A5/DeviceAgent-Runner.app
  2016-10-05 10:26:43.214 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] (
  )
  2016-10-05 10:26:43.214 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] ERROR: Could not find any Provisioning Profiles suitable for resigning
  2016-10-05 10:26:43.214 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] ERROR:       identity: #
  2016-10-05 10:26:43.214 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] ERROR:    device UDID: 9ef528263f678e344c12a2eb922653c217e34177
  2016-10-05 10:26:43.214 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] ERROR:            app: /var/folders/h2/q9ywrcbs6w327h78fljhbv280_x7vl/T/4ADB341C-5CC4-43C7-BF5B-F16A1E082537-12863-000012B5333F73A5/DeviceAgent-Runner.app
  2016-10-05 10:26:43.214 iOSDeviceManager[12863:237303] Error creating product bundle for /var/folders/h2/q9ywrcbs6w327h78fljhbv280_x7vl/T/4ADB341C-5CC4-43C7-BF5B-F16A1E082537-12863-000012B5333F73A5/DeviceAgent-Runner.app: Error Domain=com.facebook.XCTestBootstrap Code=0 "Failed to codesign /var/folders/h2/q9ywrcbs6w327h78fljhbv280_x7vl/T/4ADB341C-5CC4-43C7-BF5B-F16A1E082537-12863-000012B5333F73A5/DeviceAgent-Runner.app" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to codesign /var/folders/h2/q9ywrcbs6w327h78fljhbv280_x7vl/T/4ADB341C-5CC4-43C7-BF5B-F16A1E082537-12863-000012B5333F73A5/DeviceAgent-Runner.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc47548d9a0 {Error Domain=sh.calaba.iOSDeviceManger Code=5 "Could not resign with the given arguments" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Could not resign with the given arguments, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The device UDID and code signing identity were invalid forsome reason.  Please check the logs.}}}

```
    install
            -u,--update-app <true-or-false> [OPTIONAL]      When true, will reinstall the app if the device contains an older version than the bundle specified     DEFAULT=1
            -c,--codesign-identity  <codesign-identity> [OPTIONAL]  Identity used to codesign app bundle [device only]      DEFAULT=
            -a,--app-bundle <path/to/app-bundle.app>        Path .app bundle (for .ipas, unzip and look inside of 'Payload')
            -d,--device-id  <device-identifier>     iOS Simulator GUID or 40-digit physical device ID
```

(RuntimeError)
  ./features/support/01_launch.rb:27:in `Before'

Comment: Looks like almost all of the frameworks are missing.

Comment: @Linus G :Can you please elobarate your comments. and also i would appreciate , if you can give hint what to be done

Comment: Multiple times it is saying `ThisAndThatFramework.framework could not be loaded`. Maybe adding all these frameworks to your project helps like [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200859/frameworks-missing-in-xcode). Also, your device's UDID isn't valid as it states in the last line. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27321477/3397217).

Comment: Please use Stack Overflow markdown formatting for your code blocks.  And read the error messages.  On my side of the fence, I will try to improve the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR: Could not find any Provisioning Profiles suitable for resigning   
ERROR:   identity: iPhone Developer: xxxxxx@gmail.com (W95FEZS38E)
ERROR:   device UDID: 9ef528263f678e344c12a2eb922653c217e34177
```

As the error says, there is no valid provisioning profile installed on your machine to resign the DeviceAgent-Runner app.

1. You might have valid profile, but the device is not in the profile.
2. The profile might not be installed on the phone.
3. The might be no profile that matches the cert you provided (W95FEZS38E)
4. There might be a bug in the resigning code.

I recommend generating a Wildcard Provisioning Profile in your developer account and signing it with the W95FEZS38E certificate.  Then download and install that provisioning profile.